# Stored Procedure expects parameter: Parameter is shown in profiler ...?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, dbcontext

I am calling a stored procedure from a `DbContext` using `SqlQuery()`.  When I run the query I get the error `Procedure or function 'p_Insert_Phones' expects parameter '@Number', which was not supplied.`  What am I missing here? I see the `@Number` parameter.

```
declare @p5 nvarchar(255)

set @p5=NULL

exec sp_executesql N'p_Insert_Phones',
     N'@Number int,
     @PhoneTypeId int,
     @ReturnId nvarchar(255) output',
     @Number=0,
     @PhoneTypeId=0,
     @ReturnId=@p5 output

select @p5
```

### EDIT

Procedure definition

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Insert_Phones]
(
    @Number int,
    @PhoneTypeId int,
    @ReturnId uniqueidentifier out
) 
AS 
DECLARE @id TABLE(
    ReturnColId uniqueidentifier
) 

BEGIN TRAN 
    INSERT INTO Phones ([Number],[PhoneTypeId]) 

    OUTPUT inserted.Id 
    INTO @id 
    VALUES (@Number,@PhoneTypeId) 
COMMIT TRAN 

SET @ReturnId = (SELECT ReturnColId FROM @id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a stored procedure that is found in the database.  The parameters that you provide will not be found by the stored procedure.  I resolved the issue by including the stored procedure as the sql in the DbContext call.

```
var sqlInsert = "DECLARE @id TABLE(ReturnColId uniqueidentifier) " + 
"BEGIN TRAN INSERT INTO Phones " +
    "([Number],PhoneTypeId]) " +
    "OUTPUT inserted.Id " +
    "INTO @id " +
    "VALUES (@Number,@PhoneTypeId) " +
"COMMIT TRAN " +

"SET @ReturnId = (SELECT ReturnColId FROM @id)"

var sqlTransaction = context.Database.SqlQuery(type, insertProcedure, parameters.ToArray());

foreach (var record in sqlTransaction) { } // executes the lazy loading in order to
                                           // populate the out parameter.

Guid newId = new Guid(parameters[parameters.Count - 1].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following :

```
this.context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("p_Insert_Phones @Number = {0}, @PhoneTypeId = {1}", 0, 0);
```

Where `this.context` is the context you want to use ofcourse. The generic type parameter for the `SqlQuery` method is the return type of the query result, in your case is a nvarchar which results in a string type.

(Untested, but it's a mockup based on code i used somewhere within one of my projects).

Comment: This doesn't work because the stored proc is still expecting @ReturnId.